# Session Timeout Message in RoR using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I have an application secured with devise and a session timeout of 30 minutes. With devise all is working well for normal navigation, if the user clicks on a link when timed out they get redirected back to the login screen with a message saying "Your session expired, please sign in again to continue.", excellent.

However I have ajax in a lot of places. If the session times out and the user does an ajax operation I want the same behavior as above rather that silently failing with a 401 error in the background.

So far I have this jquery code on each page to catch 401s and reload:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, error) {
  switch(error.status) {

    case 401: {
      // unauthorised (possible timeout)
      location.reload();
      break;
    }
```

It works well enough, but there is an annoying issue:

Because the ajax request hits devise first, when my application reloads the page I get directed to the login page, but I don't see the timeout message, I see the unauthenticated "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." message.

Is there a way to ensure that on the second request devise still shows the timeout message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that you need to manually show this message, for example by redirecting to a specific url or setting some query parameter.

the problem is, that after your 401 request you got a new session and when you reload the browser, the next request will hit your application with an empty session. that's why you get the unauthenticated message.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout message "Your session expired. Please sign in again to continue" is available in `xhr.responseText`, so one approach would be to just display that:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, error) {
  switch(error.status) {

    case 401: {
      // unauthorised (possible timeout)
      location.reload();
      alert(xhr.responseText);
      break;
    }
```

To me this seems to flow better:  click **Update** on an Ajax form, get an alert that the session has timed out, then see "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing" in the flash on the signin page.